Need help in printing the correct contract output in shell program
I want to get the expected output from the input.
I have written below program to get the expected output and I almost got the output but the only problem i'm facing here is the placement of comma. The program is randomly inserting comma in the output. Help me to correct it.
input:
Tenant                       : PROD
Application                  : PROD_ANP
AEPg                         : EPG_VL-408
BD                           : BD-VL-408
uSeg EPG                     : no
Intra EPG Isolation          : unenforced
Proxy ARP                    : none
Policy Tag                   : 49165
Vlan Domains                 : PROD_PhysDom
Consumed Contracts           : Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-450,Cont_
                              EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL
                              -408_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-443,Cont
                              _EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_V
                              L-408_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-408_
                              EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL
                              -447,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-441,C
                              ont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-442
Provided Contracts           : Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-450,Cont_
                              EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL
                              -408_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-454,Cont
                              _EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-441,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-447,Cont_EPG_V
                              L-408_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-408_
                              EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL
                              -443,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-449,C
                              ont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-442

Tenant                       : PROD
Application                  : PROD_ANP
AEPg                         : EPG_VL-409
BD                           : BD-VL-409
uSeg EPG                     : no
Intra EPG Isolation          : unenforced
Proxy ARP                    : none
Policy Tag                   : 49165
Vlan Domains                 : PROD1_PhysDom
Consumed Contracts           : Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-450,Cont_
                              EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL
                              -499_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-443,Cont
                              _EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_V
                              L-499_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-499_
                              EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL
                              -447,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-441,C
                              ont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-442
Provided Contracts           : Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-450,Cont_
                              EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL
                              -408_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-454,Cont
                              _EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-441,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-447,Cont_EPG_V
                              L-408_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-408_
                              EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL
                              -443,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-449,C
                              ont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-442

Program:
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize variables to hold the values
current_consumed_contracts=""

# Function to print the current values
print_values() {
    echo "$current_consumed_contracts"
}

# Read input line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # If the line starts with "Consumed Contracts", extract and format the value
    if [[ "$line" == "Consumed Contracts"* ]]; then
        # Extract the consumed contracts value
        current_consumed_contracts=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr -d '[:space:]')
        # Read the next line and append it to consumed contracts until it starts with another field
        while IFS= read -r next_line && [[ ! "$next_line" =~ ^[A-Za-z].* ]]; do
            # Concatenate the values with a comma and without space
            current_consumed_contracts+="$(echo "$next_line" | tr -d '[:space:]'),"
        done
    # If the line starts with any other field, print the consumed contracts and reset the value
    elif [[ "$line" =~ ^[A-Za-z].* ]]; then
        if [ -n "$current_consumed_contracts" ]; then
            print_values
            current_consumed_contracts=""
        fi
    fi
done < input.txt

# Print the final consumed contracts value
if [ -n "$current_consumed_contracts" ]; then
    print_values
fi

getting output: (comma positioning is incorrect)
Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-450,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL,-408_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-443,Cont,_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_V,L-408_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-408_,EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL,-447,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-441,C,ont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-442,
Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-450,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL,-499_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-443,Cont,_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_V,L-499_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-499_,EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL,-447,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-441,C,ont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-442,

expected output:
Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-450,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-443,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-447,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-441,Cont_EPG_VL-408_EPG_VL-442
Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-491,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-450,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-492,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-446,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-471,Cont_EXT_EPG,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-443,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-454,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-449,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-445,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-444,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-452,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-451,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-447,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-448,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-441,Cont_EPG_VL-499_EPG_VL-442


The comma is added in this line: current_consumed_contracts+="$(echo "$next_line" | tr -d '[:space:]')," If you don't want to add the comma, don't do it.

HI Choroba, thanks for pointing this out. It has now given me the expected output.

This looks like you would want to refactor the whole thing to an Awk script.
awk '/^Consumed Contracts *:/ { cc=1; consumed = $0;
    sub(/^Consumed Contracts *: */, "", consumed); next }
  /^Provided Contracts *:/ { print consumed; cc = 0 }    
  cc { sub(/^ */, ""); consumed = consumed $0 }
 END { if (cc) print consumed }'

Demo: https://ideone.com/wnXiiN
